# 'ref is not a prop' even when using ref example from docs

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-select, react-redux-form

I get this warning:

`` Warning: CreatableSelect: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. ``

I use ref in intended way as [documentation says](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), pretty much copy paste from docs (except it is used for component, not basic DOM node).

But still react thinks that I'm silly and don't know that ref is reserved.
How do I tell react that I am using ref as callback ref and not for other wrong purpose?

The code works great, the only problem is error in console.

```
class SearchableSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selector = null;
    this.setSelectorRef = element => {
      this.selector = element;
    };
  }

  handleBlur() {
    const { inputValue } = this.selector;
    this.selector.createNewOption(inputValue);
  }

  render() {
    const { formatMessage } = this.props.intl;
    const placeholder = this.props.placeholder ? formatMessage({ id: this.props.placeholder }) : '';

    return (
      <Creatable
        value={this.props.value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        options={this.props.options}
        arrowRenderer={null}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        onBlurResetsInput={false}
        clearable= {false}
        noResultsText= {null}
        promptTextCreator= {(label) => {return formatMessage({ id: 'searchable.addNew' }) + ' ' + label;}}
        autoBlur= {true}
        onBlur={() => this.handleBlur()}
        ref={this.setSelectorRef}
        onFocus= {this.props.onFocus}
        autosize= {false}
        style= {this.props.style}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Creatable>
    );
  };
};
```

Snippet from other file where this component is placed:

```
<Control
  model=".assetTag"
  component={SearchableSelect}
  mapProps={{
    value: props => props.viewValue
  }}
  controlProps={{
    placeholder: 'device.assetTagPlaceholder',
    options: this.state.assetTagOptions,
    onChange: this.autoFillFields.bind(this),
    onFocus: this.updateOptions.bind(this)
  }}
  style={{ border: this.state.missing.assetTag ? '1px dotted red' : '' }}
/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the ref? Placing one on something that's not a DOM element doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JJJ I'm trying to get reference to Select input from react-select, as described here - https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1764 The point is to call component `createNewOption` method on onBlur event

Comment: [the last 'Multi-select text input' example](https://react-select.com/creatable) isn't more suitable?

Comment: @xadm it doesn't retain value on blur, just on enter. And I don't need multi-select. My solution works, but warning in console is just extra noise for other developers, since I'm not actually trying to use ref as prop :D

Comment: why there is `CreatableSelect`? source of this? can you create [mcve] on stackblitz?

Comment: @xadm I think `CreatableSelect` is the underlying name in react-select, it is just imported it as `Creatable`. Thx for mentioning stackblitz, didn't know about it. Will make example as soon as I have some time.

Comment: hmmm, [github finds it only in examples](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CreatableSelect&type=) as imported from `Creatable` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid thet it complains about that line

```
const { inputValue } = this.selector;
```

which is equal to

```
const inputValue = this.selector.inputValue;
```

**Accessing child property** (or method) **is usually** (except specific cases, f.e. `focus()`) **a sign of bad structure - state should be lift up**. Passing handlers helps lifting state up. Unfortunetelly (as you wrote) `onBlur` event doesn't pass value to handler - but we can get the input value earlier (and save it in state). `onKeyDown` handler example ([the last one](https://react-select.com/creatable)) shows that and it's simple to extend it with `onBlur` handler:

```
handleKeyDown = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
  if (!inputValue) return;
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'Enter':
    case 'Tab':
      console.group('Value Added');
      console.log(value);
      console.groupEnd();
      this.setState({
        inputValue: '',
        value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)],
      });
      event.preventDefault();
  }
};

handleOnBlur = () => {
  const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
  if (!inputValue) return;
  console.group('Value Added');
  console.log(value);
  console.groupEnd();
  this.setState({
    inputValue: '',
    value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)],
  });
};
```

IMHO `Tab` and `Enter` are quite good options (UX).

There are a few another possibilities/props: `isValidNewOption`, `getNewOptionData` - second one seems to be a better option ('validated') than using ref and accesing `raw` input value.

You don't have to use `createNewOption` method as all `options` are passed as prop - you can modify passed array.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing inputValue or doing anything else in handleBlur didn't make any difference. And while I understand the state approach you're suggesting, I'm dealing with third-party package, which does this kind of state management already behind the scenes and adding same thing on top of it is rather tricky and results in state duplication in my wrapper.  I also googled [this doc](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) which shows that what I'm doing is perfectly fine and shouldn't display any error, so still fighting. Thanks anyway. :)